# Get list of fields in empty table using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, postgresql, qgis-3

I have seen many examples of how to get the list of fields, but almost all using the layer that is already on the map, what I need is to create a new layer but from the structure of one that exists in PostGIS that when it has elements there are no problems, but when this is empty it is not possible to obtain the list of fields of its structure.

This is part of the code

```py
def AddPostgisLayer_to_gpk(self,esquema,esquemagrupo,loadlayer, tipo,strtipo,nomenclatura):
    uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
    urilistacampos = QgsDataSourceUri()
    GpName = 'd:\\temp\\' + nomenclatura + '.gpkg'
    options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
    urilistacampos.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "bdsapromat", "postgres", "postgres",
                                 QgsDataSourceUri.SslDisable)
    urilistacampos.setDataSource(esquema, loadlayer, "geom",  "geocodigo like " + tipo)
    urilistacampos.setSrid("4326")

   vlayerlistfields = QgsVectorLayer(urilistacampos.uri(), loadlayer, "postgres")
    vlayercreada = QgsVectorLayer()

    # Get its list of fields
    inFields = vlayerlistfields.dataProvider().fields()

        if strtipo == "_areal":
            vlayercreada = QgsVectorLayer('MultiPolygon?crs=EPSG:4326', loadlayer, 'memory')
        if strtipo == "_lineal":
            vlayercreada = QgsVectorLayer("MultiLinestring?crs=epsg:4326", loadlayer, "memory")
        if strtipo == "_puntual":
            vlayercreada = QgsVectorLayer("MultiPoint?crs=epsg:4326", loadlayer, "memory")
        if strtipo == "_textos":
            vlayercreada = QgsVectorLayer("MultiPoint?crs=epsg:4326", loadlayer, "memory")

        # Copy the fields  into the new layer

        adiciono = vlayercreada.dataProvider().addAttributes(inFields.toList())
        vlayercreada.updateFields()
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayercreada, False)

    if vlayercreada.isValid():
        options.layerName = esquemagrupo + "." + loadlayer + strtipo
        if os.path.isfile(GpName):
            options.actionOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteLayer  

        options.EditionCapability = QgsVectorFileWriter.CanAddNewLayer
        error = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(vlayercreada, GpName, options)
```

I am using QGIS 3.10.3.

Comment: I can see an indentation issue precisely in  line where is 'vlayerlistfields' variable.

Comment: thanks, @xunilk, but I think it's not a problem with indentation, the code is executed but if the table doesn't have any record, it doesn't return the list of the fields. The type of field that the postgis table has is geometry and qgis does not accept that type of geometry, so I have to create a new layer in memory, assign it a geometry type based on the variable "strtipo" and add the fields that the table has. consulted.

Comment: For me if i add the empty table (from postgresql/postgis) to QGIS i can list the fields, but it does not list any fields if i create the layer without adding the layer to map.

Comment: What I'm looking for with this code is to create a new empty table with geometry of type line, point or polygon depending on the value of the variable "strtipo", because the original table of postgis its field is of type Geometry and in qgis it cannot add that layer and I need to get the list of fields to pass it in the creation of the layer in memory and I don't know why when the post table is empty I can't get the list of fields